# Where did this portal lead?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

At the end of Season 4, Ghost Rider

> opened up a portal with his chain, and took the Darkhold through it.

Where did this portal lead? It didn’t look much like “Hell,” where one might imagine he might take the Darkhold (given that it originally came from there, and he said he wanted to take Aida “home,” her own matter apparently having originated in “Hell”). It actually looked sort of mountainous.

Is there any suggestion about where he went?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### My initial assumption was the Himalayas to be stored in the Sanctum there under mystic guard and key. It seems reasonable the Darkhold if it couldn't be destroyed, that it be constantly protected and watched by people unable to be tempted by it.

Since the visual effect used by Reyes resembled the magical sling-ring portals created by Dr. Strange and other mystics, I would imagine he was taking the book to the mountain stronghold of the former Ancient One.

**Update:** Even after checking around, no one has been able to define conclusively where the Darkhold ends up. A number of Wikis imply the Darkhold was taken back to the Dark Dimension, but that doesn't make sense since the MCU has made the Dark Dimension extremely hard to access during the Doctor Strange movie.

While the Ghost Rider appears to have significant supernatural power, it seems unlikely he would try and move the Darkhold to a place where Dormammu would welcome an opportunity to review its pages.

Its current location remains unknown.

Comment: Nice one! I had thought about that, but I wasn’t totally sure. Did the writers say anything?

Comment: I was kind of hoping that it could be destroyed, but with the Ancient One is safer than most other places. Is it the Ancient One or Doctor Strange who’s in charge of the Sanctum there at this point? Does this occur before or after *Doctor Strange*?

Comment: Likely after Dr. Strange. The timelines have tended to run in parallel between the movie MCU and AOS. In the Canon comic Universe the Darkhold can't BE destroyed. I suspect the MCU version can't be either.

Comment: Did they say the Darkhold came from the Dark Dimension initially? It *would* make sense from the name.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the same planet where Simmons got stuck. The mountains and lighting was same as per my view.

Comment: For people who don't remember said planet, it'd be nice if you could [edit] in a picture of something to show how it's a match :)

Answer (score 0):

Robbie mentions other universes and worlds that would seem like hell to a human. That could mean anything. The world in question might be one that's environmentally benign but is in endless war. It could be one where ordinary beings like humans are enslaved and abused. Just think about the world Hive was trapped on. Environmentally, not all that hostile but Simmons would probably agree that it had been close to hell for her, and Will certainly thought it was before he died.

Comment: Wasn’t the world Hive was trapped on filled with sand and high winds?